# Appropriate ASP.NET control to display detailed information of a record

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, detailsview, formview

This is a example of what I am trying to archive [image]

(source: http://store.apple.com/us/product/H7537LL/A/)

I need to display data (mostly text, also have picture and files) from database to a webpage (this could be a product information or a job description or something like that...), what the the appropriate control that developer often use I can use to archive this.

When inserting text (multi-lines) from a textbox to database table, HTML is not allowed so when I pull data out to display them again to the webpage, the break line characters were lost all I get is bunch of text without line break.

I am having a hard time to find the way to save and retrieve, display data, any advices or comments are appreciated.

Comment: You should look up HTMLEncode for this and use that before storing it, and decode it when it comes from the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can use **asp.net Repeater** control

Please refer this [**LINK**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more detail about Repeater control

Answer (score 1):

The Repeater control is useful if you need a high degree of control over the generated HTML. Also see the DetailsView control. [Here is MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567.aspx) describing these controls.

Repeater

> The Repeater control is a data-bound container control that produces a
>   list of individual items. You define the layout of individual items on
>   a web page using templates. When the page runs, the control repeats
>   the layout for each item in the data source. For information about
>   programming the Repeater control, see Repeater Class in the MSDN
>   library.

DetailsView

> The DetailsView control gives you the ability to display, edit,
>   insert, or delete a single record at a time from its associated data
>   source. The DetailsView control displays only a single data record at
>   a time, even if its data source exposes multiple records. For
>   information about programming the DetailsView control, see DetailsView
>   Class in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a second answer based on your edited question.

The page like the Apple one you linked to (if it were written in ASP.NET) would be comprised of many different controls, so there isn't any one control that's going to work well for this situation. You're going to end up needing to create an entire page. For that, the only suggestion is to study basic ASP.NET Web Forms to create your page, then load the production information based on the product specified in the URL.